# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'

Tags: node.js, promise, chaining

I am trying to get the search result to display on my html page and eventually in a form. The issue is my .map function when I run the code I am only able to see the record I am searching in the console.
Any suggestions?
I am using nodejs, express and html.

```
 //Get sop number by combining url with data from input box
    getInfo();
    function getInfo() {
      document.getElementById("form");
      button.onclick = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const url = "http://localhost:6600/api/sopId";
        let sopSearch = document.getElementById("sop");
        fetch(`${url}/${sopSearch.value}`, {
          method: "GET",
        })
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw Error("ERROR");
            }
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            const html = data.data.map((receipts) => {
              return `<p>SopNumber ${receipts.SOPNUMBE}</p>`;
            });
            console.log(html);
            document
              .querySelector("#app")
              .insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", `<h1`);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(data)

const html = data.data.map((receipts) => {
              return `<p>SopNumber ${receipts.SOPNUMBE}</p>`;
            });
```

Please console the data first and then check whether there is something like data.data and if data.data is an array as you are mapping to it

Hopefully you will get your answer

Comment: Sure, Thanks for your concern. I will start commenting instead of answering

Comment: No not quite, the data shows on the console already it just, I want the data to show on my html page.